# Android Studio version 4.1 can not see flutter, dart plugin

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins

Good day!

After updating or installing Android Studio (version 4.1.0), I started getting this error. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.2 at D:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 84f3d28555 (4 weeks ago), 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
    • Engine revision b8752bbfff
    • Dart version 2.10.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at D:\AppData\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\AppData\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to install the android studio flutter plugin. caused by it.
Just install plugins.
**Studio >> File> Settings> Plugins> Browse Repositories**
Search for flutter.
Tap on Install (a dialog will pop regarding dart dependency. Click Yes).
Once the installation is finished restart android studio.

[image]

Comment: I followed all steps but same problem

Comment: install both package and restart.